# Can't use color_mode = 'grayscale' with grayscale JPEGs

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I'm using tensorflow v 2.3.1

This is my code:

```
train_batches = ImageDataGenerator(preprocessing_function = tf.keras.applications.vgg16.preprocess_input).flow_from_directory(
    directory = train_path, target_size=(224,224), classes = ['1', '2', '3'], color_mode = 'grayscale', batch_size = 20)
```

Errors out with :

```
...    
    231   else:
    232     x[..., 0] -= mean[0]
--> 233     x[..., 1] -= mean[1]
    234     x[..., 2] -= mean[2]
    235     if std is not None:
IndexError: index 1 is out of bounds for axis 2 with size 1
```

I thought, documentation says, grayscale is how jpeg will be preprocessed.

Any ideas about the cause?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the pre_processing function scales the pixels between -1 to +1 so it is easy to write your own function to do this.

```
def preprocessor (xarray):
    xarray=(xarray/127.5)-1
    return xarray
# then use this function as the preprocessing function in the generator
preprocessing_function =preprocessor
```

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation of [`tf.keras.applications.vgg16.preprocess_input`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/applications/vgg16/preprocess_input) (**emphasis** is mine):

> Arguments
>
> **x** :   A floating point numpy.array or a tf.Tensor, 3D or 4D **with 3 color channels**, with values in the range [0, 255]. The preprocessed data are written over the input data if the data types are compatible. To avoid this behaviour, numpy.copy(x) can be used.

You can't use that function with grayscale images. You will have to implement your own pre-processing function.